# If we deploy streams app multiple times which has state, does tasks assigned to instances may change and it's rebuild state from earliest?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

If there are no changes to number of kafka topic partitions and number of streams app replicas, if we redeploy the app does streams app build it's internal state from earliest? does stream tasks assign to the instances change? I see it changes sometimes. 
Ex: If we are running 12 partitions on 4 instances.

Answer (score 1):

> does streams app build it's internal state from earliest

If there was no local state store in `/tmp` for [`state.dir` config](https://kafka.apache.org/24/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#state-dir), then yes.

> does stream tasks assign to the instances change?

It can, as per any Kafka Consumer Group.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! If tasks(partitions) assigned to instances change then statestore in temp/ would have different internal state right? as it may have internal state of other partitions?

Comment: It's possible, yes. I believe that directory is further divided by partition